# How do I transfer my Orangedox account to another user without losing history?

Tags: orangedox

I want to transfer my Orangedox account to one of my colleagues so that he can take over my whole history of shared links and download statistics etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we don't have a way for you to transfer your account to another, since your account will be tied to a Dropbox User Id.  You can email us directly at *support@orangedox.com* and let us know a little bit more on why you need it transferred.

FYI I work for Orangedox.